How to prevent XAML Live Preview window to show when start debugging?
In Visual Studio 2022 17.11.3, the XAML Live Preview window is open when I start debugging a WPF application.
I do not want to use it at the moment, so I would like to disable it instead of having to close it every time.
Copilot tells me to disable the "Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML" option, but there is no such option. There is also no gear icon (settings) with an option to disable it.
Any ideas on how to disable it?

Based on my researching, I find that indeed there is no options to disable the XAML Live Preview window.
However, there is an alternative method you could use.
Please try the following method:


XAML live preview can be disabled by going to the
Tools → Options... → Debugging → XAML Hot Reload
and unchecking the WPF (or other unneeded) option in Enable XAML Hot Reload section.
